# dir-paginate and custom filter row count

Tags: angularjs, pagination

So I am using [dir-paginate](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination) which is working as it should. But I want to show an overall total.
Before using dir-paginate I had the code like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">

    <h3>Excluded ({{ excluded.length }})</h3>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="product in controller.products | exclude: controller.model.filters as excluded">
                    <td><img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{ product.preview.lowRes }}" /></td>
                    <td>{{ product.details.title }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

which was fine. But when using pagination like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">

    <h3>Excluded ({{ excluded.length }})</h3>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr dir-paginate="product in controller.products | itemsPerPage: 10 | exclude: controller.model.filters as excluded" pagination-id="excluded">
                    <td><img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{ product.preview.lowRes }}" /></td>
                    <td>{{ product.details.title }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

The issue is that it shows **10** instead of the actual total. Does anyone know how I can get the total row count instead of the rows on the current page?